# Mongoose.js - I can't get the ID of a Mongoose.Model instance (MongoDB Document)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I'm doing a simple Mongoose.Model instance find() which returns a a random document from an employee collection. The thing is, I can't seem to be able to get it's ID. When I see the document contents with MongoLab, I get the following:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "554cef2fb6bb56cc421dd47c"
    },
    "name": "Bill Gates",
    "role": "Software Engineer Associate",
    "age": 21,
    "hardware": [],
    "__v": 0
}
```

But when I try to get the ID with commands on the employee instance that came back like employee._doc._id I get the following:

```
Object {_bsontype: "ObjectID", id: "ULï/¶»VÌBÔ|"}
```

What's going on? I've debugged my code and tried to find that _id property but it's just nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably include more code snippets in your questions so that it's a bit easier to identify where your flaw lies, but here is an example of how your code *should* look.

Your model should be exported from the schema:

```
var Employee = Storage.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema);
```

And your query should look something like this:

```
Employee.findOne(<--your query here-->).exec(function(err, employee) {    
  if (err) {
    //always handle errors here :)
  }
  if (employee) {
    //You can access the objectId of the employee like
    console.log(employee._id);
  }
});
```